# how can hibernate entities be named differently from the domain entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, domain-driven-design, naming

how can hibernate entities be named differently from the domain entities? Since there are both domain entities and hibernate entities that have the same name (eg: organization, customer etc.)
Is there a way by which the hibernate entities can be named in a way that communicates those are related to data layer?

Comment: Well, the packes should already be different and you might also want to use different modules for visibility and accessability (depends on your architecture). Additionally you could try to use some common prefix or suffix - it's up to you and your team how you name your classes and structure your application to convey that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same name for domain entities and hibernate entities in different packages. But same package you cannot use same name. In that case you can use different name for hibernate entity classes. (Like OrganizationEntity, CustomerEntity) It is more visible and accessible.

You should enter Correct table name within @Table(name="Customer") annotation.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhRA1.png)